# PreLie Operads and Free PreLie Algebras

Tags: reference-request, operads

Is there any relationship between Free Pre-Lie Algebras and Free Algebras over the Operad Pre-Lie (like in [KOSZUL DUALITY FOR OPERADS](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.1228v1.pdf) in pg 13 )? If there is, can someone indicate a reference for this?

So, why is a Free Pre-Lie Algebra the Free Algebra associated with Operad Pre-Lie? Moreover, is this true in general?

Comment: Well, they are the same thing by definition, no ?

Comment: @CaptainLama By the style of my question, note that I'm a little confused. The definition I know of Free Pré-Lie Algebra is a free object in the category of Pré-Lie Algebras.  So, why a Free Pré-Lie Algebra is the Free Algebra associated with Operad PréLie? Moreover, this is true in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a general fact about operads. Let $\mathtt{P}$ be any operad (e.g. the pre-Lie operad) in a symmetric monoidal category $\mathsf{C}$. If I understand your question correctly, you have two definitions of "free algebra" you want to compare:

- The forgetful functor $U : \mathtt{P}\text{-alg} \to \mathsf{C}$ has a left adjoint $F_\mathtt{P}$, and a "free algebra" is an algebra of the type $F_\mathtt{P}(X)$. It is characterized by the relation:
  $$\hom_{\mathtt{P}\text{-alg}}(F_\mathtt{P}(X), A) \cong \hom_\mathsf{C}(X,U(A)),$$
  in other words any morphism $f : X \to A$ in $\mathsf{C}$ induces a unique morphism $F_\mathtt{P}(X) \to A$ that "extends" (along the morphism $X \to F_\mathtt{P}(X)$) $f$.
- The "free $\mathtt{P}$-algebra" functor $S(\mathtt{P})$ which is given by:
  $$S(\mathtt{P},X) = \mathtt{P} \circ X = \bigoplus_{n \ge 0} \mathtt{P}(n) \otimes_{\Sigma_n} X^{\otimes n},$$
  with a $\mathtt{P}$-algebra structure induced by the operad structure of $\mathtt{P}$.

Then both functors are naturally isomorphic. This is Proposition 5.2.1 in *Algebraic Operads* by Loday and Vallette. It's not too hard to prove, you should try it before reading the proof.

Comment: Thank you! It was exactly what I needed. :)