# Free algebra over an operad

Tags: abstract-algebra, operads

So i read somewhere that 
"The free dendriform algebra can also be considered as the free algebra over the Dendriform operad."
Now i am familiar with free algebras and free operads, but i am not sure what the concept of a free algebra over an operad means exactly.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1758022/prelie-operads-and-free-prelie-algebras?rq=1) could be helpful.

Comment: i didn't fully understand that, i don't know much category theory. could you give the definition of a free algebra over an operad? i haven't been able to find it anywhere?

Comment: See Definition $2.2$ [here](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS/mayi.pdf).